# 'module' object has no attribute 'schema'

Tags: python-2.7, schema

I have a problem while running some code from the training:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'schema'
```

My schema is stored in `schema.py` file

Anacoda Navigator, spyder, Python 2.7, W10

```
import schema

SCHEMA = schema.schema
```

While running  the first file I got a problem:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'schema'
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my code. I found this site that was able to answer this question.

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50397/schema.Schema

Update your line to

```
SCHEMA = schema.Schema
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.

The structure of my files are as following:

```
├── apps
│   ├── schema
│   |   └── schema.py
│   └── users
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── schema.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── transportation
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

According to the structure all schemas are located in `apps.schema.schema.py` file.

**Schema.py**

```
import graphene
from graphene import ObjectType

import [some queries from models]

class Query (apps.users.schema, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

There are two ways to resolve this problem.

1. Go to `settings.py` files and add this line to it.

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'apps.schema.schema.schema'
```

2. Go to `urls.py` and add the following line:

```
from apps.schema.schema import schema
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema))
]
```